# Xcode UITableViewController and MainViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a problem with my app. I have storyboard, which have class MainViewController. Than I added UITableView, after I create class domainListController < UITableViewController. But I dont know how assign my UITableView with domainListController. Can you help me?

Comment: you can create domainListController<UITableViewCell.

Comment: Sorry but i dont know how update my UITableViewController. This is it http://pastebin.com/6XtxDVkb. Sorry but I am novice :/

Comment: you just want to use table in your project..?

Comment: I wanna that on top will be input and under it will be table.

Comment: you can add tableview with an easy method...

Comment: Yes I did but. I dont know update my UITableViewController to UITableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in new project, there is one viewController, add tableview in it.

now add one tableViewCell in tableView.

then add UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate in .h after your ViewController name

```
yourViewController:UIViewController**<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>**
```

Now in ViewDidLoad

```
yourTableViewName.dataSource = self;
yourTableViewName.delegate = self;
```

Now you have to implements the three delegates methods of the tableView.

whenever you want to update the data

```
[yourTableViewName reloadData];
```

Comment: I did everything but my table is empty and I dont know why. This is my update http://pastebin.com/aUYNKqbe

Comment: No. Always empty table but I have data in core data.

Comment: Can be error there ? _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

Comment: is this _fetchedResultsController successfully fetched the records from core data....??

Comment: When I add write _fetchedResultsController it return me <NSFetchedResultsController: 0x8d2af00>

Comment: can you store data in array from core data...?